# Quarkus GraalVM native build fails in AWS Lambda with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, aws-lambda, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

I want to create a java project with quarkus and want to use GraalVm for ahead of time compilation to lower cold startup times in AWS lambda.

When I deploy it in AWS Lambda and run Test I get the following error:

```
Class not found: de.timguy.lambda.GreetingLambda: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.timguy.lambda.GreetingLambda. Current classpath: file:/var/task/
```

**Steps I took**

- Create project: https://code.quarkus.io/?g=de.timguy&a=quark2&b=GRADLE&e=io.quarkiverse.amazonalexa%3Aquarkus-amazon-alexa&e=amazon-lambda&extension-search=lambda

  - Quarkus version: 2.8.2.Final (gradle.properties)
- gradlew build -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true

> ```
> Version info: GraalVM 22.0.0.2 Java 11 CE
>  3 user-provided feature(s)
>   - io.quarkus.runner.AutoFeature
>   - io.quarkus.runtime.graal.DisableLoggingAutoFeature
>   - io.quarkus.runtime.graal.ResourcesFeature    
> Produced artifacts:
>  /project/quark2-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner (executable)
>  /project/quark2-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.build_artifacts.txt
>
> Finished generating 'quark2-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner' in 11m 54s.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 12m 52s
> ```

- AWS - create function "quark2"

  - runtime "Java 11 Coretto"
  - Edit runtime setting: Handler = de.timguy.lambda.GreetingLambda
  - Upload quark2/build/runner.zip via S3
  - Test -> ClassNotFoundException (see complete error at top)

Answer (score 3):

Quarkus will produce a special zip file when it's targeting AWS Lambda. If you open it you will see a bootstrap file. The bootstrap file is only used with the custom runtimes. The custom runtimes know to execute that when they start up.

If you deploy a native executable to a Java-managed runtime by mistake then the JVM will not be able to find your handler method because it isn't a class on the classpath but a native executable instead.

Quarkus knows how to package your Lambda function this way because you've used the amazon-lambda extension.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Ok so solely because of the AWS dependency in gradle file quarkus know what the native destination plattform should look like. Well great.

Answer (score 0):

I choosed the wrong runtime setting:

- **Lambda -> Code -> runtime settings -> "Custom runtime on Amazon Linux 2" or "Custom runtime" instead of Java11**

(Still curios about:

- the 2 different custom runtimes because both of them work. [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) couldn't help me here
- how does GraalVM / Quarkus know about my target environmet for the ahead of time compiliation?

  - yes, command line tells "native" but which docker image is fetched to build the stuff?  )